# Deleting all the files under a directory using shell script, passing file directory as an argument but do not want to delete the folder itself

Tags: linux, shell

Sample command:

./delete.sh /path/to

```
|-Path 
|- to
   |- file1
   |- file2
|-location 
   |- file3
   |- file4 
   |- file5 
   . 
   . 
   |- fileN
```

Need to delete all the files(file1,file2,file3.....fileN) inside **to** and **location** directory using script but do not want to delete **to** and **location** directory, need to delete only files in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

In `delete.sh` you should remove the files inside the directory

```
d="$1"
rm -rf $d/*
```

Comment: this will delete the directory itself